# Suppose $\beta = e^{2\pi i/7} = \cos(2\pi/7) + i \sin(2\pi/7)$. What is $w^2 = (\beta + \beta^2 + \beta^4)^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $\beta = e^{2\pi i/7} = \cos(2\pi/7) + i \sin(2\pi/7)$. What is $w^2 = (\beta + \beta^2 + \beta^4)^2$?

We have $\sum_{k=0}^6\beta^k = 0.$

So far I have figured out that $w^2 = -\beta^4 - \beta^2 - \beta - 2$. We must find a quadratic equation with integer coefficients that $w$ satisfies. How do I complete this?

Comment: So, $$w^2=-w-2$$

Comment: Agree with Lab Bhattacharjee. You have already solved the exercise at this point!

Comment: @Jyrki, Only one concern I have , that is $w$ has two values from the quadratic equation, which one to reject

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The other zero of that quadratic is $\overline{w}=\beta^3+\beta^5+\beta^6$. They differ in the sign of the imaginary part. If one plots the seventh roots of unity on the unit circle of the complex plane, it is relatively easy to see that $w$ has a positive imaginary part.

Comment: Mind you, @labbhattacharjee's question is an instance ($p=7$) of the famous [Gauss's sign problem](https://mattbaker.blog/2015/04/30/the-sign-of-the-quadratic-gauss-sum-and-quadratic-reciprocity/). When we sum up the powers $\zeta_p^k$,
$\zeta_p=e^{2\pi i/p}$, $k$ ranging over the quadratic residues modulo a prime $p\equiv-1\pmod4$, the sum always has a positive imaginary part. It wasn't immediately clear to even Gauss himself how to prove this!